How to specify multiple network interfaces in byhve
I want to add an additional network device to my bhyve virtual machine.
Here is the config:
#!/bin/sh

/usr/sbin/bhyve -c 2 -m 2048 -u -H -P \
-s 0:0,hostbridge \
-l bootrom,/usr/local/share/uefi-firmware/BHYVE_UEFI.fd \
-s 1:0,lpc \
-s 3:0,ahci-cd,/usr/share/refind.iso \
-s 5:0,virtio-blk,/VM/1.img \
-s 6:0,fbuf,tcp=:5900 \
-s 7:0,virtio-9p,shared="/shared" \
-l com1,/dev/nmdm3b31677b-af70-4b7b-9590-71c8a0415f52A \
-s 8:0,virtio-net,tap1 \
-s 8:1,virtio-net,tap2 \
-s 9:0,hda,play=/dev/dsp0 \
web

However when starting it I get Device emulation initialization error: No such file or directory error. I cannot tell what I am doing wrong. Nothing in the documentation seems to indicate that you cannot use multiple network devices. Yet it will not let me. If I remove the second tap it starts like normal.
I've tried changing the device (x:y) number to multiple variations, changing the name of the device and adding a mac to the secondary device. I cannot think of anything else to do.
Searching has been relatively unsuccessful. I found this thread but it has to do with configuring vm-bhyve. I don't like vm-bhyve and so would prefer not to use it.

Check that the tap devices actually exist.
When I was having this issue, apparently bhyve doesn't like it if the interface specific doesn't begin with tap so it has some kind of heuristic to auto-fail if it doesn't think it actually exists.  (I was trying to use a renamed tap0 as "Manager" and even though it was there it just wasn't being used)

This was indeed the case. I couldn't seem to set the name in 1 ifconfig the same way I create it. So I just named it a really high number that would be virtually impossible to reach. Worked like a charm.
